# Get list of blobs in subfolder Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-storage

I am using the JS sdk to interact with Azure storage.

I have a hierarchy that looks like:
demo (container name)
/ ID
// list of files

So I am trying to get a list of files for a specific subfolder. I assumed using `listBlobsByHierarchy` was the one to use but I can not manage to get a list of blobs for that specific folder.

My code:

```
 for await (const item of containerClient.listBlobsByHierarchy("/")) {
        console.log(item, 'ITEM')
        if (item.kind === "prefix") {
          console.log(`\tBlobPrefix: ${item.name}`);
        } else {
          console.log(`\tBlobItem: name - ${item.name}, last modified - ${item.properties.lastModified}`);
        }
      }
```

which returns

```
    { kind: 'prefix', name: '5f09b7ab047f9804a861672d/' } ITEM
    BlobPrefix: 5f09b7ab047f9804a861672d/
{ kind: 'prefix', name: '5f300119536cc32ce44c0013/' } ITEM
    BlobPrefix: 5f300119536cc32ce44c0013/
{ kind: 'prefix', name: 'test/' } ITEM
    BlobPrefix: test/
```

Now I would like to get a list of files inside folder 5f09b7ab047f9804a861672d for example

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

with azure node storage sdk, we can use te method `listBlobsFlat` and `listBlobsByHierarchy` to list blobs. The two methods have some differences. The method `listBlobsFlat` can list all blobs. The method `listBlobsByHierarchy` just can just list top folder and blobs,  which like you run "dir" under C:/. Besides, if you want to list sub blobs in the subfolder, we need to use [`prefix`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs#uri-parameters).

For example

My container structure is as below

```
hello.txt
...
test
  test.txt
  test1
     data.json
```

Code(list blobs in the folder test )

```
const {
  BlobServiceClient,
  StorageSharedKeyCredential,
} = require("@azure/storage-blob");

// Enter your storage account name and shared key
const account = "jimtestdiag924";
const accountKey ="";

// Use StorageSharedKeyCredential with storage account and account key
// StorageSharedKeyCredential is only available in Node.js runtime, not in browsers
const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  sharedKeyCredential,
);
const containerName = "testupload";
async function listBlobs() {
  const containerClient = await blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(
    containerName,
  );
  console.log("list blobs with method listBlobsFlat");
  let iter = containerClient.listBlobsFlat({ prefix: "test/" });
  for await (const item of iter) {
    console.log(`\tBlobItem: name - ${item.name}`);
  }
  console.log("list blobs with method listBlobsByHierarchy");
  let iter1 = containerClient.listBlobsByHierarchy("/", { prefix: "test/" });
  for await (const item of iter1) {
    if (item.kind === "prefix") {
      console.log(`\tBlobPrefix: ${item.name}`);
      await listblob(containerClient, item.name);
    } else {
      console.log(`\tBlobItem: name - ${item.name}`);
    }
  }
}

async function listblob(containerClient, prefix) {
  let iter1 = containerClient.listBlobsByHierarchy("/", { prefix: prefix });
  for await (const item of iter1) {
    if (item.kind === "prefix") {
      console.log(`\tBlobPrefix: ${item.name}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`\tBlobItem: name - ${item.name}`);
    }
  }
}

listBlobs().catch((err) => {
  console.error("Error running sample:", err.message);
});
```

[image]